# Convert noise measurements that used 3-dB exchange rate (ER) to 5-dB

Tags: acoustics, noise

NIOSH uses 3-dB as the exchange rate (ER) for sound measurement, while OSHA uses 5-dB as the ER. Is there any way to convert the measurements using these two approaches? If yes, how can we do that? I've heard that we can convert measurements that used 3-dB ER to 5-dB but not the other way around, but I don't know how to do that.

Thank you,

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: I presume you are talking about Recommended Exposure Level measurements, but if I am mistaken please let me know. Additionally, it could prove very beneficial if you could provide some more information along with an example (no need to use actual data if you are working with confidential or in proprietary projects).

Comment: @ZaellixA Thank you for the response. NIOSH recommends 85 dBA TWA (Time-Weighted Average) as the Recommended Exposure Limit (based on 3 dB ER). OSHA recommends 90 dBA TWA as the Permissible Exposure Limit (based on 5 dB ER). Sound measurements based on these limits would be different. You can find the results for these measurements in this link: https://academic.oup.com/annweh/article/49/6/493/176857?login=false

Comment: @ZaellixA you can find the measurements based on 3-dB ER as Leq and measurements based on 5-dB ER as Lavg. I don't know if there is any way to convert these measurements. I had some search and some people say that there is no way to convert the measurements and some people say that we only can convert the measurements that used 3-dB ER to 5-dB but not the other way around.

Comment: @milmo thanks for the information. I'll have a look and come back to you if I have any contribution to make. It may take some time though as I am quite busy lately. I'll do my best.